# Is there a way to compress a file into a customized extension?

Tags: c#, .net, compression, customization

As the title says, I'm thinking about a project, and that project involves file compression, I want to know if there is a way to compress any file into a customized extension like a video file of 50MB compressed to 30MB? but the extension will not be .zip or .rar, I want to "create" an extension so the output file would be "compressedFile.some".

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could actually just rename it. We did that one a project some years ago.
Compress the file with a zip library, renam and done.

Even microsoft does it. Go rename an xlsx or docx file to .zip and take a looksie inside.

Comment: but I can use the zip compressor library and instead of putting `string output = "testFile.zip"` and I can write `string output = "outFile.abc`. Did I understand?

Comment: Yes, just compress the file with the zip library as normal, and name the output file with the extension you require. I have seen libraries that wont do that, but even then you can still rename it afterwards.